# Detect object in an RGB image (MATLAB R2014a)

Tags: image, image-processing

An image leaf set with background 1:

[image: An image leaf set with background 1]

Can you help me? I want to detect object and convert these to binary image. The object is just a leaf. I have been using a toolbox in MATLAB but the code of image 1 cannot be used in image 2.

An image leaf set with background 2:

[image: An image leaf set with background 2]

Comment: How can you expect  an algorithm to guess which leaf you want ?

Comment: i used  color segmentation matlab's apps and convert the code to function, but when i try to other picture of the leaf its not work properly. Can you help me?

Comment: How can you expect an algorithm to guess which leaf you want ?